# Changing pictures with changing opacity

Tags: javascript

I have built a code which change pictures every 5 second using setinterval() and everytime when a picture is changes, it will show up with it's opacity growing from 0 to 1, using setinterval() as well.
It all works excellently, but there is a single problem which I can find the way to fix it. The problem is that after I start the page, if I move to a differend tab, if I come back in a minute, it all goes craze and the opacity is growing too fast and more then once before a picture is changed.
Here is the code:

```
var images = [], x = 0, t = 0, timerid, s = 0;
    images[0] = "Images/" + location.pathname.substring(1, location.pathname.length - 5) + "2.jpg";
    images[1] = "Images/" + location.pathname.substring(1, location.pathname.length - 5) + ".jpg";
    function ChangeOpacity() {
        img = document.getElementById("img");
        s += 0.003;
        t = s.toString();
        img.style.opacity = t;
        if (img.style.opacity>=1) {
            s = 0;
            clearInterval(timerid);
        }
    }

    function SwitchImage() {
        img = document.getElementById("img");
        img.src = images[x];
        img.style.opacity = 0;
        timerid = setInterval('ChangeOpacity()', 1);
        x++;
        if (x >= images.length)
            x = 0;
    }
    function StartFun() {
        setInterval('SwitchImage()', 5000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `window.onblur` and `window.onfocus` function. Each time the tab loses focus (onblur) you could clear the interval and restart it when the tab gets focused again (onfocus).

[More about focus on tabs](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/detect-browser-window-focus)

Edit:
Restarting the interval is not necessary in all cases.

Comment: Hey
it sounds great, I'll try your idea and keep you updated.

Comment: Where should I add those functions?

Comment: Just define them on the top of your script, like this: `window.onblur=function(){…}; window.onfocus=function(){…}`

Comment: I did that and it works well, execpt when I return to the tab, the picture's opacity is 0.something and it keeps being like that until the picture is changed...

Comment: You could add a statement to the onblur or the onfocus function which sets the opacity to 0. This should solve the problem.

Comment: I added that:
onblur = function() {
            img.style.opacity = "0";
            clearInterval(timerid);
        }

        onfocus = function() {
            img.style.opacity = "0";
            setInterval('ChangeOpacity()', 1);
        }

Comment: Maybe you have to reset `s` too.

Comment: Oh, it's my fault: Don't restart the interval when the window gets back its focus. And reset the opacity to *__1__*.

Comment: Images are not loading, but: __SUCCESS__! [Temporary Link](https://siphalor.lima-city.de/test/image-change.html)

Comment: In my browser it works. Even if i leave the window for several minutes. Only the images don't like to load...

Comment: Success too. My images are now loading: I just messed up the file extensions.